# Android Build Failed to Generate Signed APK after upgrade to Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-app-signing, android-studio-4.2

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key .... from store "----------": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

It failed with saved password but it build correctly when i manually type password and next time it fails again

Remember passwords checkbox is checked in Build Signed Bundle or APK Window

Comment: It might be a bug, introduced in 4.2 as I also experienced "Remember password" option corrupting the remembered text.

Comment: Yes, It might be a bug in Android Studio 4.2

Comment: Are you also getting warnings about obfuscated code and uploading mapping files? I never used to get this warning and the mappings automatically uploaded...

Comment: Other people are pointing out the same issue.

Comment: The issue still exists in Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 16, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in Android Studio 4.2

You Have to Manually Type Password Each time you Generate Signed APK

**Update**

This bug is also in Android Studio 4.2.1 and Android Studio 4.2.2

**Update**

This Bug Is Fixed in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Hence Upgrading to Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Solves the Problem

Comment: Definitely, a sneaky way for Google to push us to use Play App Signing. How this is not fixed for so long?

Answer (score 1):

I still have this problem on 4.2.1,but the key.jks can work on 4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded to 4.2.1, the problem still exists.

Comment: Same here. It seems to be necessary to enter both passwords again every time.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed!

Versions:

- Arctic Fox RC 1 | 2020.3.1.21
- 4.2.3